# How to build dnn first in opencv with CMake?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I want to build dnn first in OpenCV with CMake.
The OpenCV version is 3.4.
I find a way add_dependencies(), 
but I can't find add_executable(), add_library(), or add_custom_target() in dnn CMakeLists.txt.

How do I modify dnn CMakeLists.txt to build dnn first?

The following is the content of dnn CMakeLists.txt

```
if(WINRT)
  ocv_module_disable(dnn)
endif()

if(DEFINED BUILD_opencv_dnn AND NOT BUILD_opencv_dnn)
  return()
endif()

include(${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/OpenCVFindLibProtobuf.cmake)
if(NOT Protobuf_FOUND)
  ocv_module_disable(opencv_dnn)
endif()

set(the_description "Deep neural network module. It allows to load models from different frameworks and to make forward pass")

ocv_add_dispatched_file("layers/layers_common" AVX AVX2)

ocv_add_module(dnn opencv_core opencv_imgproc WRAP python matlab java js)
ocv_warnings_disable(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wno-shadow -Wno-parentheses -Wmaybe-uninitialized -Wsign-promo
                                     -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes
)
ocv_warnings_disable(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS /wd4701 /wd4100)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ocl4dnn/include ${OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if(MSVC)
  add_definitions( -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 )
  ocv_warnings_disable(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4018 /wd4355 /wd4800 /wd4251 /wd4996 /wd4146
                                       /wd4305 /wd4127 /wd4100 /wd4512 /wd4125 /wd4389 /wd4510 /wd4610
                                       /wd4702 /wd4456 /wd4457 /wd4065 /wd4310 /wd4661 /wd4506
  )
else()
  ocv_warnings_disable(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wno-deprecated -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wshadow
                                       -Wunused-parameter -Wunused-local-typedefs -Wsign-compare -Wsign-promo
                                       -Wundef -Wtautological-undefined-compare -Wignored-qualifiers -Wextra
                                       -Wunused-function -Wunused-const-variable -Wdeprecated-declarations
  )
endif()

if(APPLE_FRAMEWORK)
  ocv_warnings_disable(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wshorten-64-to-32)
endif()

if(ANDROID)
  add_definitions(-DDISABLE_POSIX_MEMALIGN -DTH_DISABLE_HEAP_TRACKING)
endif()

#supress warnings in autogenerated caffe.pb.* files
add_definitions(-DHAVE_PROTOBUF=1)
ocv_warnings_disable(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
    -Wunused-parameter -Wundef -Wignored-qualifiers -Wno-enum-compare
    -Wdeprecated-declarations
    /wd4125 /wd4267 /wd4127 /wd4244 /wd4512 /wd4702
    /wd4456 /wd4510 /wd4610 /wd4800
    -wd858 -wd2196
)

if(PROTOBUF_UPDATE_FILES)
  file(GLOB proto_files ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/tensorflow/*.proto)
  list(APPEND proto_files ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/caffe/opencv-caffe.proto)
  set(PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP_APPEND_PATH ON) # required for tensorflow
  PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(Protobuf_HDRS Protobuf_SRCS ${proto_files})
else()
  file(GLOB fw_srcs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/tensorflow/*.cc)
  file(GLOB fw_hdrs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/tensorflow/*.h)
  list(APPEND fw_srcs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/caffe/opencv-caffe.pb.cc)
  list(APPEND fw_hdrs ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/caffe/opencv-caffe.pb.h)
  list(APPEND Protobuf_SRCS ${fw_srcs})
  list(APPEND Protobuf_HDRS ${fw_hdrs})
  list(APPEND Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/caffe)
  list(APPEND Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/misc/tensorflow)
endif()

ocv_source_group("Src\\protobuf" FILES ${Protobuf_SRCS} ${Protobuf_HDRS})
ocv_module_include_directories(include ${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ocv_glob_module_sources(${Protobuf_SRCS} ${Protobuf_HDRS} ${CBLAS_H_PROXY_PATH})
ocv_create_module(${Protobuf_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
ocv_add_samples()
ocv_add_accuracy_tests()
ocv_add_perf_tests()

ocv_option(${the_module}_PERF_CAFFE "Add performance tests of Caffe framework" OFF)
ocv_option(${the_module}_PERF_CLCAFFE "Add performance tests of clCaffe framework" OFF)
if(BUILD_PERF_TESTS)
  if (${the_module}_PERF_CAFFE)
    find_package(Caffe QUIET)
    if (Caffe_FOUND)
      add_definitions(-DHAVE_CAFFE=1)
      ocv_target_link_libraries(opencv_perf_dnn caffe)
    endif()
  elseif(${the_module}_PERF_CLCAFFE)
    find_package(Caffe QUIET)
    if (Caffe_FOUND)
      add_definitions(-DHAVE_CLCAFFE=1)
      ocv_target_link_libraries(opencv_perf_dnn caffe)
    endif()
  endif()
endif()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "build dnn **first**"? Do you want to build that target **before all others** targets? You cannot do that, because build process, generated by CMake, is all about **dependencies**: targets can be built in any order while their dependencies are satisfied. However, you may request to build a **specific target**. E.g. with make it is simply `make dnn`. So only build process will only build `dnn` and its dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I want to build that target before all other targets.

Comment: The OpenCV is in Yocto BSP, so I think I need to modify CMakeList.txt. If I want build dnn before another target, how do I do?